# OpenVPN algorithms configuration to allow only TLS 1.3

Tags: openvpn

For my OpenVPN configuration, I have chosen only 3 symmetric ciphers: AES-256-GCM, AES-128-GCM, and also CHACHA20-POLY1305.

I don't have any fallback algorithm. I support only modern clients.

Is this enough or should I also specify that only TLS 1.3 is allowed (option tls-version-min 1.3)? Am I right that these algorithms are only in TLS 1.3 so even though not directly specified there is only TLS 1.3 possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you specified your ciphersuites using the `tls-ciphersuites` options, this is not enough. This option specifies which ciphersuites are enabled for TLS v1.3: this options **does not** configuration the ciphersuites used for TLSv1.2 and below.

For TLS v1.2 and below, you must use `tls-cipher` configuration. If you did not specify this option and if you did not disable TLSv1.2 and below, TLSv1.2 should be enabled with the default ciphers.

Answer (score 0):

TLS 1.3 has other benefits besides just ciphersuites.  Mostly in the name of performance but also patching up some latent security issues in the handshake (encryption/signing).

Is it enough to merely restrict ciphersuites?

Depends on the threats one is worried about but most likely yes for an individual user.

Is there something to gain from specifying only TLS1.3?

Yes.